# Convergence and sum of the series $\sum\left(L-a_n\right)^2$, where $a_0=0$ and $a_{n+1}=(a_n)^2+\frac{1}{4}$ and $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find out whether the series $\sum\left(L-a_n\right)^2$ converges (where $\{a_n\}$ is the sequence defined by the recurrence relation $a_0=0$ and $a_{n+1}=(a_n)^2+\frac{1}{4}$ and $L$ is its limit) and, if it converges, also its sum.

I have previously managed to prove that $\{a_n\}$ is a strictly increasing sequence which is bounded above by $\frac{1}{2}$ and I also know that it converges to $\frac{1}{2}$, so the series is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}-a_n\right)^2.$

To study the series I have first tried the ratio test and I got:

$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-a^2_{n+1}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{1}{2}-a^2_{n}\right)^2}=\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}-a^2_{n+1}}{\frac{1}{2}-a^2_{n}}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}-a^2_n-\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}-a^2_{n}}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\frac{1}{4}-a^2_n}{\frac{1}{4}a_n}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-a_n\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-a_n\right)}{\frac{1}{2}-a_n}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}+a_n\right)^2\xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=1$ so the test is inconclusive.

I have also tried to use Raabe's test but I got that $0<n\left(\frac{(\frac{1}{2}-a_n)^2}{(\frac{1}{2}-a_{n+1})^2}-1\right)=n\left[\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+a_n}\right)^2-1\right]\leq\frac{7}{9}n\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ so it seems that this is inconclusive too

(since Raabe's test tells us that if there exists $K>1$ such that $n\left(\frac{(1/4-a_n)^2}{(1/4-a^2_{n+1})^2}-1\right)\geq K\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ then the series is convergent while if $n\left(\frac{(1/4-a_n)^2}{(1/4-a^2_{n+1})^2}-1\right)\leq 1\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ then the series is divergent and in this case I haven't been able to verify neither of the two conditions).

I have also thought about using the comparison test but it isn't clear to me to which series I should compare this series too and the root test is also inconclusive.

Thus, I would appreciate if someone would point out to me how to go about studying the convergence of this series. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $a_{n+1}-a_n = a_n^2-a_n+\frac 14 = (a_n-\frac 12)^2$.

Hence the series $\sum_n (a_n-\frac 12)^2 = \sum_n (a_{n+1}-a_n)$ is amenable to telescoping.

$\sum_{n=0}^N (a_n-\frac 12)^2 = a_{N+1} - a_0 = a_{N+1}$, hence the series converges and its sum is $\lim_n a_n = \frac 12$.